# Why eigenvectors of a symmetric toeplitz matrix has a particular property?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I got a **positive-definite symmetric toeplitz matrix** $\mathbf{A}$, for example,
$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 &2 &3 \\ 2& 1& 2 \\ 3& 2& 1  \end{array} \right] 
\end{equation}$.

It can be eigen-decomposition as
$\mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{A}\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{\Lambda},$

where $\mathbf{U} =
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2 &  \mathbf{u}_{3} \end{array} \right]$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e.,

$\mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{U}^T = \mathbf{I}$,

with $\mathbf{I}$ being the identity matrix, and

$\mathbf{\Lambda} = \mathrm{diag} \left( \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_{3} \right)$

is a diagonal matrix. The orthonormal vectors $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_{3}$ are the eigenvectors corresponding, respectively, to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,  \lambda_{3}$ of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, where these eigenvalues are ordered from the smallest to the largest, i.e., $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2  \leq \lambda_{3}$.

Also, I have a special vector $\mathbf{d}$, whose **each element has norm $1$**, for example,  $\mathbf{d} = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\1 \end{array} \right]$.

I found a particular situation, i.e.,
$\mathbf{d}^H\left(\mathbf{u}_1\mathbf{u}^T_3 + \mathbf{u}_3\mathbf{u}^T_1 \right) \mathbf{d} = 0$. ( the eigenvectors corresponding the smallest and largest eigenvalues, and $^H$ denotes complex-conjugate transpose.)

It seems that it can be generalized to general examples. But I wonder why?

Comment: This is not true. It is easy to generate a random counterexample by computer when $A$ is $5\times5$.

Comment: @user1551 the result cannot be fulfilled using two arbitrary eigenvectors, but the eigenvectors corresponding the smallest and largest eigenvalues. Maybe you can give me a counterexample?

Comment: Try $A=\pmatrix{
 3&-1& 0&-1& 1\\
-1& 3&-1& 0&-1\\
 0&-1& 3&-1& 0\\
-1& 0&-1& 3&-1\\
 1&-1& 0&-1& 3}$ for instance.

Comment: @user1551 How beautiful! Thank you very much.